# Git: Crash "less" of git diff vs. "terminal" from vim?

Tags: git, vim, less

##### Environments

```sh
❯ sw_vers
ProductName:    macOS
ProductVersion: 11.6.1
BuildVersion:   20G224

❯ git --version
git version 2.31.1

❯ less -V
less 590 (PCRE2 regular expressions)
Copyright (C) 1984-2021  Mark Nudelman

❯ vi --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.2 (2019 Dec 12, 빌드한 날짜 Feb 22 2022 22:17:00)
macOS 버젼 - x86_64
포함된 패치: 1-4450
Compiled by Homebrew
...
(omitted details)
```

I'd like to write commit messages with `git diff`'s output at right, in a vertical window of vim.

##### Expected

In some git working dir, I can make what I expected with:

```sh
❯ vim "+bo vert ter git diff" "+winc p" .git/COMMIT_EDITMSG
```

- `:bo[tright] vert[ical] ter[minal] git diff`: run `git diff` in a new termial, vertical window at right.
- `:winc[md] p`: and come back to the previous window, where to edit the commit message.

##### Problem

But when `git commit` with `GIT_EDITOR` variables like above, it fails:

```sh
# [alias] cm = commit -as
❯ GIT_EDITOR='vim "+bo vert ter git diff" "+winc p"' git cm
```

With `GIT_TRACE`, I assumed there is a conflict between vim and less from `git diff`:

```sh
❯ GIT_TRACE=2 GIT_EDITOR='vim "+bo vert ter git diff" "+winc p"' git cm
23:21:41.599932 git.c:733               trace: exec: git-cm
23:21:41.600666 run-command.c:667       trace: run_command: git-cm
23:21:41.601180 git.c:390               trace: alias expansion: cm => commit -as
23:21:41.601190 git.c:794               trace: exec: git commit -as
23:21:41.601194 run-command.c:667       trace: run_command: git commit -as
23:21:41.607190 git.c:447               trace: built-in: git commit -as
힌트: 편집기가 파일을 닫기를 기다리는 중입니다... 23:21:41.620256 run-command.c:667       trace: run_command: GIT_INDEX_FILE=/Users/hansuk/dotfiles/.git/index.lock 'vim "+bo vert ter git diff" "+wincmd p"' /Users/hansuk/dotfiles/.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG
(-------- Above here, printed in the terminal where the `git commit` is running --------)
(-------- Followings are printed in the vim's right vertical terminal ------------------)
23:21:41.745108 git.c:447               trace: built-in: git diff
23:21:41.746732 run-command.c:667       trace: run_command: unset GIT_PAGER_IN_USE; LESS=FRX LV=-c less
```

How could I fix it? Do I need to dig the git's codes?

Comment: FWIW, `$ git commit -v` adds the unified diff below the boilerplate so you may not need that hack to begin with.

Comment: I knew it :)
But I'm trying to make two different points over that: 1. in another window, 2. display vertically, not below

Comment: Well, if you have the diff below you can `vim +vs +19 +norm\ zt` instead of all that complexity.

Comment: The line 19 should be changed dynamically for lines of a commit message template or change statuses, files.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "crash". I don't think there's any actual bug here though. To avoid having the diff output run through the pager, use `--no-pager` if needed.

Comment: My point is, `vim "+bo vert ter git diff" "+winc p" .git/COMMIT_EDITMSG` works well with 'less'(git diff) in the new vertical terminal, but `GIT_EDITOR='vim "+bo vert ter git diff" "+winc p"' git cm` doesn't. With `--no-pager` option has same results except it prints diff outputs in new terminal not runs less.